# Architecting a Neo4j-Based Application - stick to vanilla API using plain nodes & relationships or use Spring/GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, neo4j, spring-data-graph, spring-data-neo4j

I'm hoping to hear from any of you who have architected and implemented a decent sized Neo4j app (10's millions nodes/rels) - and what your recommendations are particularly w.r.t modelling and the various APIs (vanilla java/groovy Neo4j vs Spring-Data-Neo4j vs Grails GORM/Neo4j).

I'm interested if it actually pays off to add the extra OGM (object-graph-mapping) layer and associated abstractions?

Has anyone's experience been that it is best to stick to 'plain' graph-modelling with nodes+properties, relationships+properties, traversals and (e.g.) Cypher to model and store their data?

My concern is that 'forcing' a particular OGM abstraction onto a graph database will affect future flexibility in adapting/changing the domain model and/or flexibility in querying the data.

We're a Grails shop, and I have experimented with GORM/Neo4J and also with spring-data-neo4j.

The primary purpose for the dataset will be to model and query relationships amongst v.large numbers of people, their aliases, their associates and all sorts of criminal activity and history. There will be more than 50 main domain classes. There must be flexibility in the model (which will need to evolve rapidly in the early phases of the project) and in speed and flexibility of querying.

I have to confess, I'm struggling to find a compelling reason to use a OGM layer when I can use (e.g.) POJOs or POGOs, a little Groovy magic and some simple hand-rolled domain object <-> node/relationship mapping code. As far as I can tell, I think I would be happy just dealing with nodes & traversals & Cypher (aka KISS). But I would be very happy to hear others' experiences and recommendations.

Thanks for your time & thoughts,

TP

Answer (score 7):

since I'm the author of the Grails Neo4j plugin, I might be biased. The main reason for creating the plugin was to apply the ease of Grails domain classes with their powerful out-of-the-box scaffolding to Neo4j for ~80% of the use cases. For the other 20% where specific requirements require stuff like traversals etc. we're using Neo4j APIs directly (traversals/cypher) and do not use the GORM API.

The current version of the Neo4j plugin suffers from a supernode issue since each domain instance is connected to a subreference node. If multiple concurrent requests (aka threads) add new domain instances there is chance to get a locking exception. I'm about to fix that either by a sub-subreference approach or by using indexing.

Cypher can also be used in the Neo4j Grails plugin.

Spring-Data-Neo4j on the other hand is a more advanced approach with finer control over mapping details, but requires usage of specific annotations. And I found no easy way to integrate that into Grails in a way scaffolding works.

We're using the predecessor version of the plugin in a productive application with ~60k users and ~10^6 rels. Due to NDA I cannot provide more details on that.

Comment: Thank Stefan, actually I was going to get in contact with you directly to ask you about 'real-life' experience with the GORM/Neo4J plugin. I'm trying to avoid common architectural & coding 'gotchas' when using Neo4J, especially in the case where an object-graph-mapping layer is used.

Answer (score 0):

We do not use grails, but do use a hybrid plain neo4j / spring-data-neo4j solution. The reason is based on the fact that some of our domain data has a fixed schema and some doesn't. SDN takes a lot of the burden away and can be mixed with plain neo4j if the need arises.

We have classes that describe a data model, the objects for these classes we persist using SDN, with no additional tricks, we just use the basics from SDN. Then we have classes that contain the data for the model that is not known beforehand. These are stored in nodes contain special properties for describing what model type the data refers to. When neo4j 2 gets released, we will probably move that info into labels. Between these nodes there can be relations, also described by the aforementioned data model managed by sdn. We also have relations from the generic nodes to SDN nodes, which works fine, as everything ends up being the same things: nodes.

We have not encountered any issues yet using this approach. The thing we love the most is that the data of which we do not know in advanced how it will be modelled, is stored in the way you would have wanted to store data when you would have known it in advance, making the data actually match the model chosen, which is very hard to do when using any other type of (non-graph) database.

Comment: "When spring 2 gets released": you probably meant "neo4j 2"?